# Java's URL openStream() can it not use HTTPS?

Tags: java, android, https

I was tinkering on android with WMS Layers. One of the services I want to load the layer from is serving them via Https.  The wms layer example i found though uses:

```
InputStream input = null; 
  try {
   input = url.openStream();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
  }
```

Where url is a type URL and is set to a url that uses HTTPS.  This throws an error as I suspect I have to set up my certificates or something.  Is there anyway to just say accept brute force this to accept the certs?  I tried something similar to this in c# and was able to just basically making a call to this:

C# code to make the https work:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
...
...

  public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification,
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        //this might be useful later too
        //http://blog.jameshiggs.com/2008/05/01/c-how-to-accept-an-invalid-ssl-certificate-programmatically/
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: you probably need to add your root certificate on the phone. Also, use HttpClient

Comment: is HttpClient more robust?  I did find some snippet of code that did a post to https.  I wonder if I can fashion that snippet to serve my purposes.  I will investigate this root certificate too...I don't do much http anything so it is all new to me.